# How to convert the following sql into QueryDSL form?

Tags: java, querydsl

How to convert the following sql into QueryDSL form?

```
SELECT user.name,la.library_id,l.library_name,lr.coun
FROM library_admin la
LEFT JOIN user on la.user_id = user.id
left join library l on la.library_id = l.id 
left join (SELECT lend_admin_id ,COUNT(lend_admin_id) coun FROM lend_record
         GROUP BY apply_status, lend_admin_id
         HAVING apply_status = 'APPROVED') lr
        on lr.lend_admin_id = la.user_id

order by la.library_id;
```

Comment: If you'd like a useful response, you might consider reviewing your tags.  People tend to only look at questions they have a vested interested in - specifically your [tag:QueryDSL] experts *probably* won't be looking at [tag:jquery] which is for manipulating web pages.

Comment: Rulong, could you make a start on this? Do you have a bare-bones Java program to run a simple `SELECT * FROM mytable` query using the library you are referring to?